# Running custom scripts during build/compile in node js visual studio

Tags: node.js, .net, visual-studio

I have created a sample app https://github.com/ajithvallabai/TestMethod in Visual studio 2019 . I want to run prebuild and build scripts in package.json https://github.com/ajithvallabai/TestMethod/blob/master/TestMethod/package.json#L10-L11 when we build the solution . Is there any way to do it ?

(In this app there is no build-events option in Project>properties

This method is only working for "buid" command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-npm?view=vs-2022 that too it needs additonal files like .ts files .tcx files . but i want to run custom commands.

You can give answer for VS19/VS22 also